# Center widgets within a layout in Vaadin Flow

Tags: java, layout, vaadin, centering, vaadin-flow

When I have small widget such as a `LoginLayout` within another layout appearing in a much larger window, how can I center the content? I want the content to appear approximately in the middle of the window with respect to both width and height.

I found older Questions on this topic such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28559028/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41416572/642706), but they are for the previous generation of [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) (versions 6, 7, 8) before Flow (versions 10+, now 14).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## `HorizontalLayout` with CSS3 *Flexbox*

The trusty [`HorizontalLayout` and `VerticalLayout` classes](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-ordered-layout) from olden days are still in Vaadin 14. This pair of classes have been retrofitted to use modern [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) technology found in [CSS3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_3). See excellent tutorials on Flexbox at [CSS-Tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). CSS3 Flexbox is *very* close conceptually to the behavior of classic Vaadin `HorizontalLayout` and `VerticalLayout`.

In this example below we start with a Vaadin [`HorizontalLayout`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/orderedlayout/HorizontalLayout.html).

```
final public class AuthenticateView extends HorizontalLayout
```

In the constructor, add your widget to the layout, a [`LoginForm`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginForm.html) being the widget in this example.

```
this.add ( new LoginForm() );
```

Make the `HorizontalLayout` to use all the available room with regards to both the width and the height.

```
this.setSizeFull ();
```

Set our content in the layout (our `LoginForm`) to move to the middle horizontally across. The verb “justify” here refers to [typographer/designer lingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment#Justified) where justification means alignment to the margin of the page.

```
this.setJustifyContentMode ( FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.CENTER );
```

Lastly, we can specify where our content should appear vertically within our now-very-tall layout. Do we want content at the top, at the bottom, or in the middle?

Notice the difference in syntax here from the Vaadin 8 generation: The term [`FlexComponent`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/orderedlayout/FlexComponent.html) reflects the use of CSS Flexbox.

```
this.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment ( FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER );
```

Bonus feature: Let's verify visually the behavior of our `HorizontalLayout` by coloring its otherwise invisible edges.

```
this.getStyle ().set ( "border" , "6px dotted DarkOrange" );  // DEBUG - Visually display the  bounds of this layout.
```

Set this view to be default via the `@Route` annotation.

```
@Route ( "" )
final public class AuthenticateView extends HorizontalLayout
```

When run we find our login form appearing centered within our much bigger web browser window. Notice the orange border showing how our `HorizontalLayout` has grown to take the entire window.

[image: screenshot of Vaadin LoginForm widget appearing centered within a much bigger web browser window.]

For fun, try disabling the various lines of code shown here. Run the app to see the impact the code has on behavior by noticing the placement of the `LoginForm` and the orange border.

Here is complete class code.

```
package work.basil.example.ui;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.login.LoginForm;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.login.LoginI18n;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.FlexComponent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@Route ( "" )
final public class AuthenticateView extends HorizontalLayout
{
    // Constructor
    public AuthenticateView ( )
    {
        super ();

        // Widgets
        this.add ( new LoginForm () );

        // Arrange
        this.getStyle ().set ( "border" , "6px dotted DarkOrange" );  // DEBUG - Visually display the  bounds of this layout.
        this.setSizeFull ();
        this.setJustifyContentMode ( FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.CENTER ); // Put content in the middle horizontally.
        this.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment ( FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER ); // Put content in the middle vertically.

    }
}
```

---

Caveat: This code shown above is nowhere near sufficient for real-world login work. The focus here was on widget layout, not user authentication.